# Redis Session State EVAL TimeOut

Tags: azure, redis

I am trying to use Redis Session State with my Windows Azure Cloud website. I am using the 1 GB Standard Tier. I am using the P1 Premium Database. I am testing on local host. My cache and website are located on EAST US.

I am storing 200 - 400 objects in session state, which include an order and its payments.

Here is the error:

An exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' occurred in Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Timeout performing EVAL, inst: 0, mgr: Inactive, err: never, queue: 7, qu: 1, qs: 6, qc: 0, wr: 1, wq: 1, in: 0, ar: 0, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=8,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=1,Free=4094,Min=8,Max=4095), clientName: XX

Here are my settings:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore">
  <providers>
    <add name="MySessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" host="XX.redis.cache.windows.net" accessKey="XX" ssl="true" syncTimeout="3000" connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds="5000" operationTimeoutInMilliseconds="1000" retryTimeoutInMilliseconds="3000" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Answer (score 0):

late answer perhaps, but never the less...
in this case, it looks like the amount of info within the cache is your problem. Redis is fine tuned to retrieve a lot of small cached info, not a single huge string...

Another thing i'd suggest you to try is to increase the number min number of IOCP and worker threads... in my scenario (2 core machine) i figured out that the best number is 100...